# Does Yoast support regular expression redirects to remove the date from post URLs?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I have to setup as redirect from "Date and Name" Format to "Post Name" Format.
For example:

```
/2010/10/post-url/
```

it must be redirected to

```
/post-url/
```

I am using Yoast for redirect. I don't know what it can support but I have in mind that I should add:

```
^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$
```

but will yoast redirect support that? and what should be the "New URL"?

Please let me know you have experience on adding this kind of redirect on Yoast.

Comment: Does it have to be done with Yoast?   It would be fairly easy to put a redirect rule for this into .htaccess.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it is true but I just want to know if that is applicable to Yoast Plugin